# the parameters of 'w' and 'w-' in h5py.file

Tags: python, python-3.x, h5py

In h5py, I can use the following code to open a file

```
f = h5py.File('myfile.hdf5','w')
```

According to the doc,

```
w   Create file, truncate if exists
w- or x Create file, fail if exists
```

What does "truncate" mean when using "w"? Generally speaking, what are the different scenarios of "using w" vs "using w-"?

Answer (score 0):

In this context, truncate means it will empty the file first i.e. "w" will overwrite any existing file, "w-" won't- it will fail if the file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

"truncate" means it overwrites an existing file by the same name. Using "w-" will avoid accidentally overwriting.
There is a third option. Use 'r+' if you want to open an existing file to append data.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> w   Create file, truncate if exists
> ```

The meaning is the (imitation of) creation of brand-new file:

- If a file with the  appropriate name *don't exist*, **it's created** (really, no imitation).
- If it *exists*, the **imitation of the file creation occurs** (i.e. as if it would be first deleted, and then created again).

> ```
> w- or x Create file, fail if exists
> ```

This parameter is important for safety *against unintentionally overwriting an existing file* (as opposed to parameter `"w"`, which overwrites files without a warning).